# Spring FORM tag library - radiobutton, loading its LABEL attribute from a message source

Tags: spring, internationalization, radio-button

I am working on a spring MVC-based application and use the spring tag library for form data binding. I happily used the  tag until I realised that the labels associated with individual radios were not picked up from the message source but I had them hard-coded in the JSP. I somehow failed to notice before, so now I was like going to fix this and here I encounter a silly little problem, which I hope you will be able to help me with.

Ok, this works:

```
<form:radiobutton path="metric" value="0" label="inches" />
<form:radiobutton path="metric" value="1" label="centimeters" />
```

This does not.

```
<form:radiobutton path="metric" value="0" label="<fmt:message key="label.calculator.units.imperial" />" />
<form:radiobutton path="metric" value="1" label="<fmt:message key="label.calculator.units.metric" /> " />
```

The problem is the nesting of the fmt:message tag within the format:radiobutton tag. I get **Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/calculator/calculator.jsp(15,100) PWC6212: equal symbol expected** in the stack trace.

Is there any other way to make the radio buttons' labels to load from the message source? I guess I could use `<c-rt:set>` to first set the message text from the message source into a variable and then `${varname}` it into the `label=""` attribute... but that seems a little long-winded. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Haven't used the `<form:radiobutton>` tag very often, but as far as I know you have no choice but to set the message into a variable and then use it like `label="${varname}"`.

One other option would be to loose the label attribute and just print a label by hand, something like:

```
<spring:message code="label.calculator.units.imperial" /><form:radiobutton path="metric" value="0" />
<spring:message code="label.calculator.units.metric" /><form:radiobutton path="metric" value="1" />
```

Off course the HTML result will differ. You'll have to control the label yourself instead of the radio button tag generating a `<label for="..."`.

Comment: thanks, your spring:message is interesting. I used it to set the message into var="metric" and then used label attribute of radiobutton to `${metric}` and that worked. I just didn't use `fmt:message` but `spring:message` (didn't notice it existed) and split the nested tags into two tags side-by-side. A bit of a hassle, but not so bad. I would not want to loose the ability to produce correct HTML markup by printing the message directly and not have it in a label. These labels are cool, they are clickable :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, set the 'var' attribute of the spring:message tag:

```
<spring:message var="inches" code="label.calculator.units.imperial"/>
<spring:message var="centimeters" code="label.calculator.units.imperial"/>

<form:radiobutton path="metric" value="0" label="${inches}"/>
<form:radiobutton path="metric" value="1" label="${centimeters}"/>
```